# JacksonAdapter cannot resolve correctly in azure-core-1.20 and Java web app

Tags: java, azure, ant, jackson, jackson-databind

I am using azure-core-1.20 to connect to Azure KeyVault.
It is failing on line 35.

Could anyone see a cause of this conflict?
Thank you

Failing call:

[image: Failing function]

```
java.lang.VerifyError: Bad return type
Exception Details:
  Location:
    com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/cfg/MapperBuilder.streamFactory()Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/core/TokenStreamFactory; @7: areturn
  Reason:
    Type 'com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonFactory' (current frame, stack[0]) is not assignable to 'com/fasterxml/jackson/core/TokenStreamFactory' (from method signature)
  Current Frame:
    bci: @7
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/cfg/MapperBuilder' }
    stack: { 'com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonFactory' }
  Bytecode:
    0x0000000: 2ab4 0002 b600 08b0                    

    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.json.JsonMapper.builder(JsonMapper.java:114)
    at com.azure.core.util.serializer.JacksonAdapter.(JacksonAdapter.java:133)
    at com.azure.core.util.serializer.JacksonAdapter.createDefaultSerializerAdapter(JacksonAdapter.java:192)
    at com.azure.identity.implementation.IdentityClient.(IdentityClient.java:96)
    at com.azure.identity.implementation.IdentityClientBuilder.build(IdentityClientBuilder.java:113)
    at com.azure.identity.ManagedIdentityCredential.(ManagedIdentityCredential.java:39)
    at com.azure.identity.DefaultAzureCredentialBuilder.getCredentialsChain(DefaultAzureCredentialBuilder.java:129)
    at com.azure.identity.DefaultAzureCredentialBuilder.build(DefaultAzureCredentialBuilder.java:123)
```

Current Lib for the app:
[image: azure lib]
[image: web app libs]

Try Ivy, but now jackson 2.9.9 is conflicting with 2.12.5 .
Dont know where jackson 2.9.9 is coming from. The Ivy report show no version 2.9.9

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency org="com.azure" name="azure-core" rev="1.21.0" conf="binaries->default" />
        <dependency org="com.novell.ldap" name="jldap" rev="2009-10-07" conf="binaries->default" />
        <dependency org="org.springframework" name="spring-jdbc" rev="5.3.11" conf="binaries->default" />
        <dependency org="org.apache.tomcat" name="tomcat-jdbc" rev="9.0.52" conf="binaries->default" />
        <dependency org="com.azure" name="azure-security-keyvault-secrets" rev="4.3.3" conf="binaries->default" />
        <dependency org="com.azure" name="azure-identity" rev="1.3.6" conf="binaries->default" />
        <dependency org="javax.resource" name="javax.resource-api" rev="1.7.1" conf="binaries->default" />
        <dependency org="org.springframework" name="spring-webmvc" rev="5.3.12" conf="binaries->default" />
        <dependency org="org.springframework" name="spring-context" rev="5.3.12" conf="binaries->default" />
        <!-- <dependency org="org.springframework" name="spring-jca" rev="2.0.8" conf="binaries->default" >
            <exclude module="spring-bean"></exclude>
            <exclude module="spring-core"></exclude>
            <exclude module="spring-dao"></exclude>
        </dependency>  -->
        <dependency org="commons-configuration" name="commons-configuration" rev="1.10" conf="binaries->default" />
        <dependency org="commons-collections" name="commons-collections" rev="3.2.2" conf="binaries->default" />
        <dependency org="displaytag" name="displaytag" rev="1.2" conf="binaries->default" >
            <exclude  module="jcl104-over-slf4j"></exclude>
            <exclude module="slf4j-log4j12"></exclude>
        </dependency> 
        <dependency org="com.google.code.gson" name="gson" rev="2.8.8" conf="binaries->default" />
        <dependency org="org.apache.struts" name="struts-core" rev="1.3.10" conf="binaries->default" />
        <dependency org="org.apache.struts" name="struts-taglib" rev="1.3.10" conf="binaries->default" />
        <dependency org="org.apache.struts" name="struts-extras" rev="1.3.10" conf="binaries->default" />
        <dependency org="org.apache.struts" name="struts-tiles" rev="1.3.10" conf="binaries->default" />
        <dependency org="org.apache.struts" name="struts-el" rev="1.3.10" conf="binaries->default" />
        <dependency org="org.apache.struts" name="struts-faces" rev="1.3.10" conf="binaries->default" />
        <dependency org="org.apache.logging.log4j" name="log4j-core" rev="2.14.1" conf="binaries->default" />
        <dependency org="org.apache.logging.log4j" name="log4j-api" rev="2.14.1" conf="binaries->default" />
        <dependency org="org.apache.logging.log4j" name="log4j-slf4j-impl" rev="2.14.1" conf="binaries->default" />
        <dependency org="org.slf4j" name="slf4j-api" rev="1.7.32" conf="binaries->default" />
        <dependency org="org.slf4j" name="slf4j-log4j12" rev="1.7.32" conf="binaries->default" />
        <dependency org="org.slf4j" name="slf4j-simple" rev="1.7.32" conf="binaries->default" />
        <dependency org="org.slf4j" name="jcl-over-slf4j" rev="1.7.32" conf="binaries->default"  />
    </dependencies>
```

Comment: Could you provide the `pom.xml` code to see dependencies you are used?

Comment: There is no pom.xml, this is old application.

Comment: I finally got this. ```java.lang.LinkageError: Package versions: jackson-annotations=2.9.9, jackson-core=2.9.9, jackson-databind=2.9.9, jackson-dataformat-xml=2.12.5, jackson-datatype-jsr310=2.12.5, azure-core=1.21.0```

Comment: In the Question You mentioned azure Core 1.20 and in the error it is azure-core 1.21.0. Did you updated? And, what all are the dependencies you installed for that, in the project?

Comment: Yes, I did. I also tried Ivy. code is included above.

Comment: Try update to this [dependencies compatibility version](https://azuresdkartifacts.blob.core.windows.net/azure-sdk-for-java/staging/sdk/identity/azure-identity/dependencies.html) package installations.

Comment: lol. finally. azure-core 1.4.0 works. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Try update to this [dependencies compatibility version](https://azuresdkartifacts.blob.core.windows.net/azure-sdk-for-java/staging/sdk/identity/azure-identity/dependencies.html) package installations

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same conflict when using azure-storage-file-datalake-12.15.1 where azure-core is requesting jackson versions 2.13.5.

I forced the jackson libs to use 2.15.1 version and that resolved the problem for me.
Jackson libs for me was annotations, core, databind and datatype-jsr310

I couldn't reproduce this in Eclipse but happened when running the Java app in prod, so it was quite tricky to resolve.

Still using IVY as well.

Edit:
Useful link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/sdk/troubleshooting-dependency-version-conflict